# Creating Omega Theme with HTML5

Tags: html, drupal

I am new to Drupal and want to create a site with HTML5. I have installed the latest 7.22 as well as Omega 3. Both are supposed to be HTML5, however the DTD reads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Gary

Comment: You are using the Omega theme? What version is it? Could be that you need to install a plugin in order to get it to have doctype for HTML5.

Comment: Omega 3, it is the HTML5 version, it is not supposed to require a plug in that I am aware. One of the 'selling' points is that it is 5 ready

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the RDF module. If that does not work, try adding this function to template.php.

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_html().
**/
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['doctype'] = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
  $vars['rdf'] = new stdClass;
  $vars['rdf']->version = '';
  $vars['rdf']->namespaces = '';
  $vars['rdf']->profile = '';

  // Serialize RDF Namespaces into an RDFa 1.1 prefix attribute.
  if ($vars['rdf_namespaces']) {
    $prefixes = array();
    foreach (explode("\n  ", ltrim($vars['rdf_namespaces'])) as $namespace) {
      // Remove xlmns: and ending quote and fix prefix formatting.
      $prefixes[] = str_replace('="', ': ', substr($namespace, 6, -1));
    }
    $vars['rdf']->namespaces = ' prefix="' . implode(' ', $prefixes) . '"';
  }
}
```

Comment: oh..BTW. The original omega doctype with the rdf stuff still render in html5 complience mode on all the browsers I have tested on. I have used Omega on atleast 30 sites and have never had to change the doctype. But I understand that having your page perfectly validate is a nice feeling :)

Comment: 2pha - Thank you very much for your response, I will take a look at this shortly and let you know my results. - Gary